# NetSuite Suitelet SSv2 how to populate multiselect with object

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I am trying to simply populate a multiselect field with a list of marketplaces.

Here is the marketplaces object:

```
var marketplaces = {

            amazonCom:{
                label: 'Amazon.com',
                searchId: 'customsearch_ca_export_detail_search__21',
                scriptId: 'customscript_revant_ca_catalog_export',
                deploymentId: 'customdeploy_revant_ca_catalog_us'
            },

            amazonUK:{
                label: 'Amazon.uk',
                searchId: 'customsearch_ca_export_detail_search__33',
                scriptId: 'customscript_revant_ca_catalog_export',
                deploymentId: 'customdeploy_revant_ca_catalog_uk'
            },

            amazonCA:{
                label: 'Amazon.ca',
                searchId: 'customsearch_ca_export_detail_search__23',
                scriptId: 'customscript_revant_ca_catalog_export',
                deploymentId: 'customdeploy_revant_ca_catalog_ca'
            },

            amazonFR:{
                label: 'Amazon.fr',
                searchId: 'customsearch_ca_export_detail_search__26',
                scriptId: 'customscript_revant_ca_catalog_export',
                deploymentId: 'customdeploy_revant_ca_catalog_fr'
            },

            amazonDE:{
                label: 'Amazon.de',
                searchId: 'customsearch_ca_export_detail_search__24',
                scriptId: 'customscript_revant_ca_catalog_export',
                deploymentId: 'customdeploy_revant_ca_catalog_de'
            },

            amazonIT:{
                label: 'Amazon.it',
                searchId: 'customsearch_ca_export_detail_search__29',
                scriptId: 'customscript_revant_ca_catalog_export',
                deploymentId: 'customdeploy_revant_ca_catalog_it'
            },

            amazonJP:{
                label: 'Amazon.co.jp',
                searchId: 'customsearch_ca_export_detail_search__30',
                scriptId: 'customscript_revant_ca_catalog_export',
                deploymentId: 'customdeploy_revant_ca_catalog_jp'
            },

            amazonES:{
                label: 'Amazon.es',
                searchId: 'customsearch_ca_export_detail_search__37',
                scriptId: 'customscript_revant_ca_catalog_export',
                deploymentId: 'customdeploy_revant_ca_catalog_es'
            },

            ebayCom:{
                label: 'eBay.com',
                searchId: 'customsearch_ca_export_detail_search__34',
                scriptId: 'customscript_revant_ca_catalog_export',
                deploymentId: 'customdeploy_revant_ca_catalog_us2'
            },

            ebayUk:{
                label: 'eBay.uk',
                searchId: 'customsearch_ca_export_detail_search__51',
                scriptId: 'customscript_revant_ca_catalog_export',
                deploymentId: 'customdeploy_revant_ca_catalog_uk2'
            },

            ebayAu:{
                label: 'Amazon.au',
                searchId: 'customsearch_ca_export_detail_search__50',
                scriptId: 'customscript_revant_ca_catalog_export',
                deploymentId: 'customdeploy_revant_ca_catalog_au'
            },

            ebayVolt:{
                label: 'eBay.com Volt',
                searchId: 'customsearch_ca_export_detail_search__35',
                scriptId: 'customscript_revant_ca_catalog_export',
                deploymentId: 'customdeploy_revant_ca_catalog_volt'
            }

        };
```

I am trying to follow the documentation to populate the multiselect field. Here is the code:

```
var marketplacesList = form.addField({

            id:'selectedmarketplaces',  
            type:ui.FieldType.MULTISELECT,
            label:'Marketplaces'

        });

        for (var i = 0; i<marketplaces.length; i++){

            marketplacesList.addSelectOption({

                value: marketplaces[i].label,
                text: marketplaces[i].label

            });

        }
```

Any help?

Thanks,

- Jesse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `marketplaces` is not an array, so it does not have a `length` property.

Try replacing the for line with:

```
for (var i in marketplaces) {
    if(!marketplaces.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        continue;
    }

    //  Add option for form or whatever...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am still getting a handle on javascript (obviously). Thanks for the tip. Glad it was an easy fix.

Comment: Careful with the for statement, you may enumerate properties you don't want/expect. With vanilla Javascript you should use [`Object.hasOwnProperty()`](http://brianflove.com/2013/09/05/javascripts-hasownproperty-method/) to ensure you're only accessing the properties defined in the marketplaces object. `for(var marketPlace in marketplaces) if(marketplaces.hasOwnProperty(marketPlace)) //... add to list, else continue` I prefer to use the lodash JS library which has [_.forOwn()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#forOwn) (and many other great helpers)